# Date Null when i Add event in Device Calendar in ios 6.0 but it working fine in ios 4.x and 5.x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

My app is a universal app and in a portion of my app i have to add event in calendar my code is working fine in iOS 4.x & 5.x but in i 6.0 when i convert a string into date using date formatter it return null for date in iOS 6.0 below is the code:-

```
-(IBAction) addToPlanBttnClick:(id) sender
{
    addToPlanBttn.tag =1;
    EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    EKEvent *newEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];



    // set event title start date and end date
    NSString *str = conference.SeminarDate;
    str = [[str stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:conference.StartTime];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    newEvent.title = conference.Subject;

    //NSString *pointDate = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:dateLbl.text]  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    // You can use current date or any other
    //NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[pointDate stringByAppendingString:@", 2012 "]stringByAppendingString:[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)]]];
    //NSLog(@"stri date----%@", str1);
    NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];

    NSDate* startDate = [df dateFromString:str];


    //[NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"stri date----%@", startDate);
    newEvent.startDate = startDate;
    [newEvent setNotes:conference.BriefDescription];

    NSString *str1 = conference.SeminarDate;
    str1 = [[str1 stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:conference.EndTime];
    NSLog(@"%@",str1);

    NSDate *endDate = [df dateFromString:str1];
    NSLog(@"stri date----%@", endDate);

    newEvent.endDate = endDate;
    addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
    addController.event = newEvent;
    addController.editViewDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:addController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

my date string is TUESDAY 12 FEBRUARY 2013 10:00
and date formatter is `[df setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];`as shown in code
and resulting date from string is:-2013-02-12 04:30:00 +0000 in simulator and in iPad

but it null on iOS 6.0 
Please suggest me where i am wrong.

Comment: Testing the date formatter and your date string worked fine on my iOS6 device. Are you sure that's the exact string being passed to the dateFromString method?

Comment: What's the current locale of your device/simulator? You're not setting an explicit locale on your NSDateFormatter

Comment: @AndrewTetlaw yes that string are rights..and in my simulator and iPad os 5.1.1 it working fine but in my iPhone device os 6.0 value of start date is null and it took default date 01 jan 2013 ....

Comment: @tsakoyan when i use these lines with date formatter [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [df setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES]; then still not working please suggest how can i bind the date string to date formatter so i can recive right date at any where in world.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's gonna make a difference but try NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];
    [df setLocale:usLocale];